# how do i get a list of nearby users in an android application?

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, social-networking

I am building an application with a UI that gets a list of nearby users to help connect like minded people with similar interests. I know this is not a new concept, apps like Grindr do exactly what i am trying to achieve in this. How do i go about getting profile info on the application from a phone and displaying it on another phone running the same application? is there a web-server needed for this?

to illustrate what the user would see: USER A has their character bio written up and artwork displayed, USER B is nearby and sees USER A on the home page gridview.

How could USER B getting this info delivered to his phone? What are best practices in doing this?

I looked already and couldn't find a solution to this already posted but if this has already been answered somewhere else i would appreciate links so i do not contribute to duplicate questions. I am new and needing some guidance as I start getting deeper into android programming and this is a question i seem to keep coming back to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to have all users upload their current location to you via a webservice every few minutes.  Store that in a database (using an UPSERT).  Then when a user wants to look for other nearby users, you search the database for all users within that range and return that list.  It would help to use a GIS enabled database such as Postgres witht he PostGis extention, but it isn't necessary.

Probably a good idea to stick a timestamp in the database with the location, so you can eliminate results that are too old.

Comment: YOu'd need to have their profile photos somewhere on your system.  When you send them the list of users, you'd send them some metadata on the user-  name, id (I assume they'd all have an id in your system), etc.  One of those pieces of data would be the URL of their photo.

Comment: that sounds like a good plan. thanks for the direction and help.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest that your server must not return the exact location of the other users for privacy concerns. If you want to show a distance, make the server return one with intentional random inaccuracy to prevent users from doing a precise triangulation of someone else's position.

Comment: i intend on doing this and i appreciate the concern.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to do for small distance and dont want to store data on server you can use wifi-direct to transfer data between users...However it might drain users battery..To avoid this you can use bluetooth low energy for initial detection and then wifi-direct for communication...

Answer (score 1):

Google just announced the new **Nearby API** that it does exactly what you want. It has been included in [Google Play services 7.8](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview). [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2015/07/connect-with-world-around-you-through.html) you can find a detailed blog entry from Google's blog where they explain it in detail, and [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/get-started) you have the reference page.

I'm investigating if you can configurate the search distance.

Comment: do you know approximately how far the distance would be  using DISTANCE_TYPE_DEFAULT?and is it the best strategy for the longest distance?